# Having trouble implementing the branches of Descision Trees from scratch(LONG)

Tags: python, recursion, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm currently working on implementing Decision Tree algo from scratch using Python.
I'm having trouble implementing the branching out of the tree. In the current implementation, I'm NOT using Depth parameters.

What's happening is, either the branches are ending too quickly (if I use flags to prevent a infinite recursion) or I'm running into infinite recursions if I remove the flags. I'm also having trouble understanding if I'm in the main loop or a recursive loop.

My data is pretty simple:

```
d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['three'] = (0,0,1,1)
df = np.array(df)
```

Which leads to an output of :

```
array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])
```

I'm going to be using the gini_index to make the splits. This function is not integral to solve my problem, so I will be placing it at the end of this question to aid in reproducibility.

I'm using a dictionary object `y`, which will continue to contain nested dictionaries as the branches spread.

```
                              y
                          /         \
                   y['left']               y['right']    
                  /       \                         \
   y['left']['left']   y['left']['right']              y['right']  ['right']
```

Next I will be breaking down the function for creating the tree, where is where i"m having some problems.

```
def create_tree2(node, flag ):   #node is a dictionary containing the root, which will contain nested dictionaries as this function recursively calls itself.

    left, right =node['Groups']  # ['Groups'] is a key contains that contains two groups which will be used for the next split; I'm assigning them to left and right here
    left,right = np.array(left), np.array(right)  #just converting them to array because my other functions rely on the data to be in array format. 


    print ('left_group', left)    #these are for debugging purposes. 
    print('right_group', right)

if flag == True and (right.size ==0 or left.size ==0):   
    node['left'] = left
    node['right'] = right
    flag = False
    return 

#This above portion is to prevent infinite loops.
```

With regards to infinite recursion, what was happening was, if I had two rows of data, instead of splitting the two   rows into two different nodes, 
I was getting one node with no rows, and the other node with two rows.

My loop usually stops if there is less than two rows of data in one node.
So the empty node would terminate, 
but the node with two rows of data would split again,  into an empty node and a two-row filled node. This process would continue forever. 
 So I tried using a flag to prevent this infinite loop. 
The only problem with the flag is, it seems to activate one step early., 
It's not checking if the split would result in two nodes or an infinite loop. For example:

```
A split leads to 
left = []
right =     [ [ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])]

now instead of checking if the right can split further
 (left =[3,2,1] , right =  [ 4.,  1.,  1.]),
```

the flag is stopping at the step above, one step too early.

```
if len(left) < 2:
    node['left'] =left
    return

#Here I'm ending the node, if the len is less than 2 rows of data. 




else:

    node['left'] = check_split(left)
    print('after left split', node['left']['Groups'])# for debugging purposes
    create_tree2(node['left'], True)


#This is splitting the data and then recursively calling the create_tree2 function
#given that len of the group is NOT less than two. 
#And the flag gets activated to  prevent infinite looping. 
#Notice that node['left'] is being used as the node parameter in the recursion function.





if len(right) <2:
    node['right'] = right
    return
else:
    node['right'] = check_split(right)
    print('right_check_split')
    create_tree(node['right'],False)



#doing the same thing with the right side.
```

The only problem here (so I assumed) is that if the left side recursively calls itself first, 
then the node parameter will change to  node['left'] dictionary 
and the left and right local variables 
with be updated with the left branche info.

Let's look at the output
Here is how the code looks after being called:

```
#first split

left_group [[ 1.  4.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.]]

right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
[ 4.  1.  1.]]






# first the left_group calls itself recursively producing an additional split
resulting in
a new left group that  is empty, and a right_group has two rows

left_group []

right_group [[ 1.  4.  0.]
[ 2.  3.  0.]]


# now  the `if` flag statement gets called
 `if flag == True and (right.size ==0 or left.size ==0):   
        node['left'] = left
        node['right'] = right
        flag = False
        return `


    #ideally I want to do one more  split on the right group,
 to see if right group   would split further but didn't know how to implement that properly. I'm assuming I would need some sort of counter? 


#Next it jumps to the right main branch correctly. 
not sure how as `right` was updated after    the left's recursive function


right_check_split

left_group []
right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
[ 4.  1.  1.]]


This also activates the flag which stops the iteration. Ideally I would like this to go at least one more round to check if the right group [3,2,1] and [4,1,1] would split into two branches. Not sure how to do that?
```

The other thing I'm confused about is how why the dictionary was able to start in the right main node, instead of the left's nested dictionaries.

Recall that the recursion first took place in the main left branch

```
create_tree2(node['left'] , True),
```

this should update the values of left and right, which would then carry over when we hit this portion of the function :

```
if len(right) <2:
    node['right'] = right
    return
else:
    node['right'] = check_split(right)  #This right value would have been updated on?
    print('right_check_split')
    create_tree(node['right'],False)
```

So I was worried that the right values would be changed to
 `[[ 1.  4.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.]]`but instead it remember the original right values from the root node, which was

`right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.  1.]].`

So my questions are

1) How can I implement the flag properly to check to make sure there is indeed an infinite recursion going on before initiating the `if flag loop`

2) Despite the recursive function updating the parameters with the left branches values, my function was able to use the previous right values (which is what I want) and was able to properly create the new nested dictionaries in the appropriate places.

If needed here is the full code layed out

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['three'] = (0,0,1,1)
df = np.array(df)




def split_method(data, index, value):
    left, right  = list(), list()
    for row in data:
    #for i in range((data.shape[-1] -1)):
        if row[index] < value:
            left.append(row)
        else:
            right.append(row)

return left, right





def gini(data,groups ):
    data_size = len(data)


    gini_index = 0

    for group in groups:
        group_size = len(group)
        multiplier = float(group_size/data_size)
        prob =1
        if group_size == 0:
                continue
        print('multiplier', multiplier)
        for value in set(data[:,-1]):
            prob*= [row[-1] for row in group].count(value)/group_size
            print ('prob', prob)
        gini_index +=  (multiplier * prob)

    return gini_index




def check_split(data):
    main_score = 999
    gini_index = 999
    gini_value = 999
    print('data', data)
    for index in range(len(data[0])-1):
        for rows in data:
            value = rows[index]
            groups =split_method(data, index, value)
            gini_score =gini(data,groups)

            if gini_score < main_score:
                main_score = gini_score
                gini_index, gini_value, gini_groups = index, value,np.array(groups)


    return {'Index': gini_index, 'Value': gini_value, 'Groups': gini_groups}



def create_tree2(node, flag ):

    left, right =node['Groups']
    left,right = np.array(left), np.array(right)
    print ('left_group', left)
    print('right_group', right)

    if flag == True and (right.size ==0 or left.size ==0):
        node['left'] = left
        node['right'] = right
        flag = False
        return 

    if len(left) < 2:
        node['left'] =left
        return

    else:

        node['left'] = check_split(left)
        print('after left split', node['left']['Groups'])
        create_tree2(node['left'],flag = True)

    if len(right) <2:
        node['right'] = right
        return
    else:
        node['right'] = check_split(right)
        print('right_check_split')
        create_tree2(node['right'],flag =True)




    return    node



root = check_split(df)   # this creates the root dictionary, (first dictionary)
y = create_tree2(root, False)
```

Comment: What's `root` at `y = create_tree2(root, False)`? (the last line)

Comment: Updated. So root is the first dictionary created.  
`root = check_split(df)`

Comment: It seems like an error that you do this: `if len(left) < 2: node['left'] = left; return` and do not set `node['right']` to any value. I see the same thing for `len(right)` lower down. Is this right?

Comment: Ahh! Seems to be programming mistake on my part.  I can use `continue` right?

Answer (score 1):

I made these changes to your function:

```
def create_tree2(node, flag=False):

    left, right =node['Groups']
    left, right = np.array(left), np.array(right)
    print('left_group', left)
    print('right_group', right)

    if flag == True and (right.size ==0 or left.size ==0):
        node['left'] = left
        node['right'] = right
        flag = False
        return

    if len(left) < 2:
        node['left'] = left
        flag = True
        print('too-small left. flag=True')
    else:
        node['left'] = check_split(left)
        print('after left split', node['left']['Groups'])
        create_tree2(node['left'],flag)

    if len(right) < 2:
        node['right'] = right
        print('too-small right. flag=True')
        flag = True
    else:
        node['right'] = check_split(right)
        print('after right split', node['right']['Groups'])
        create_tree2(node['right'], flag)

    return    node


d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['three'] = (0,0,1,1)
df = np.array(df)

root = check_split(df)
y = create_tree2(root)
```

Basically, I used the `len<2` checks to set the flag to True, and then allowed the right side to recurse. I still don't think this is right, because something might happen with len==1. But there's no infinite recursion.

I got this output:

```
left_group [[ 1.  4.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.]]
right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.  1.]]
after left split [array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
 array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])]
left_group []
right_group [[ 1.  4.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.]]
too-small left. flag=True
after right split [array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
 array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])]
left_group []
right_group [[ 1.  4.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.]]
after right split [array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
 array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])]
left_group []
right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.  1.]]
too-small left. flag=True
after right split [array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
 array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])]
left_group []
right_group [[ 3.  2.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.  1.]]
Y= {'Groups': array([[[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  3.,  0.]],

       [[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 4.,  1.,  1.]]]), 'Index': 0, 'right': {'Groups': array([array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
       array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])], dtype=object), 'Index': 0, 'right': {'Groups': array([array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
       array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]])], dtype=object), 'Index': 0, 'right': array([[ 3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.,  1.]]), 'Value': 3.0, 'left': array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)}, 'Value': 3.0, 'left': array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)}, 'Value': 3.0, 'left': {'Groups': array([array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
       array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])], dtype=object), 'Index': 0, 'right': {'Groups': array([array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
       array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])], dtype=object), 'Index': 0, 'right': array([[ 1.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]]), 'Value': 1.0, 'left': array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)}, 'Value': 1.0, 'left': array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)}}
```

Also, I think you can optimize this by checking at the end if a node's left or right is empty, pulling the opposite node up one. Something like:

```
if node['left'] is empty:
    kid = node['right']
    node.clear()
    for k,v in kid.items():
        node[k]=v
elif node['right'] is empty:
    same basic thing, with left kid
```

Checking for empty is a trick, because sometimes it's a dict and sometimes not.

Finally, you don't seem to be storing the actual split information. Isn't that the point of a decision tree - knowing what factors to compare? Shouldn't you record the column and value at each node?

Comment: The information is supposed to be stored through the `check_split function`;
the output of that function are keys `value` , 'index' and 'groups' which hold all the info.  I will go through your suggestions though it will take me some time (I'm still  a novice).  Thank you so much for going through my code. I spent all day yesterday, trying to understand what's going on. 
I learned a lot though.  =)

Comment: `"`Basically, I used the len<2 checks to set the flag to True, and then allowed the right side to recurse. I still don't think this is right, because something might happen with len==1. But there's no infinite recursion`"`

What do you think will happen when len ==1? Do you mean 1 in left and 1 in right?

Comment: The `len<2` checks set flag=True. But in the termination condition, you check for flag=True and len=0. So if len==1, it will set the flag, but pass by the termination. I think it's okay because the `len<2` check doesn't recurse. But it's worth either writing some test cases, or syncing up the conditions.

Comment: I don't think I have to worry about len ==1, because if len==1, there will always have to be one empty group after the recursion . If I have  one in left and one in right, it will just pass through the function without recursion.